# Probability of Distributing 52 cards among 4 players

Tags: probability

I'm attempting to understand why the following probabilities are the same: when we split a deck of 52 cards among 4 players, under the following two scenarios, with a shuffled deck: 1) player 1 gets the first 13 cards, and 2) player 1 gets the 1st card, player 2 gets the 2nd card, player 3 gets the third card, player 4 gets the 4th card, player 1 gets the 5th card. Then, the number of possible hands the first player can receive is the same in both cases.

So clearly there are 52 choose 13 different hands in both, however, for the second scenario, I'm attempting to compute in the following way: 52 options for the first card, 48 options for the second card, 44 options for the third card, etc. Which yields 52*48*44*...*4, and we need to divide out 13! to account for the fact that order does not matter in a hand of cards. Clearly, this number does not equal 52 choose 13. Am I missing something as I'm counting?

Comment: Because there aren't $48$ options for the second card to player 1. There are $51$. Which cards can't player 1 get for his second card?

Comment: Think about it this way: scenario 2 for the first player is equivalent to taking every fourth card (starting with the 1st) and putting them on top which is the same as scenario 1

Comment: Suppose there were only two cards, $A,B$.  You get one and then I get one.  How many options are there for the one I get?